# Basic Query about Spinner INVALID_POSITION

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

As per Android Docs,

public int getSelectedItemPosition ()

Since: API Level 1
Return the position of the currently selected item within the adapter's data set
Returns
int Position (starting at 0), or INVALID_POSITION if there is nothing selected.

**Now i want to know in which case/situation INVALID_POSITION is returned , since when spinner is initialized it default position is set to 0 .**

```
  Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterVehicleList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, vehicleTypeList);
    adapterVehicleList.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapterVehicleList);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    int position =spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
             position =spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is what you will get when you have an empty spinner, as nothing can be selected in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it could be when an element is selected using `setSelection(int position)` and position is negative or greater than the number of elements.

Comment: Your trying to say invalid position is return if position invalid is set using setSelection , if yes ... its not like that ... i just tried it .. if u set -20 it will return -20  and same for other case also

Comment: Apologies, I should have checked before posting.